# Is Oauth library generic or depend on the social networking site?

Tags: authentication, oauth

I have a basic doubt.
I have come across many open source OAuth libs.But all of them are dependent on the social networks they serve.
My question is that if all OAuth library depens on the sites or if there are any OAuth libraries which are truly generic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR OAuth2 implementations are similar, but differ in some details. If a library was not designed for or tested with a particular server implementation - chances are it will not work with it at all. I have yet to see a library that supports more than one provider.

Long story:
While all OAuth2 implementations are similar, devil is in the detail.
For example, comparing step 1 (request code) of Facebook and Google OAuth2 protocols:

- with Facebook you register and whitelists whole domain, for Google you list specific URLs.
- Facebook lets you append arbitrary &params to the redirect_uri, Google only allows passing &state URL param
- Google requires specifying response_type=code parameter, Facebook doesn't

Obtaining access token is not quite compatible either:

- Google allows only POST request, Facebook supports both POST and GET
- Google returns JSON response, Facebook - an URL string
- Facebook requires exactly the same redirect_uri as in step 1, Google doesn't verify presence of &state

I did not intend to put together a comprehensive list of all the deviations.
This is just some examples I've noticed while reading public documentation and experimenting with APIs.
VKontakte mostly uses Facebook's quirks, but returns JSON in step 2, similar to Google.

After you've jumped all the hoops and obtained the access token things get even harder.
OAuth does not attempt to cover how APIs are structured or accessed, so you need completely different routines to fetch user name and email from each network.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also raised this question after encountering these issues. Fb doesnt required URL to be signed but OAuth says it should be(twitter and linkedin do). I guess Fb and google have deviated a lot.

Comment: I recently discovered that Fb does support state parameter, so using it would be "cross platform". Inconsistency in JSON usage can be worked around by checking response's MIME type (Flask-OAuth does that). It now seems to me that most (all?) implementations can be brought to single common denominator. One OAuth to rule them all should exist. However, it is quite a rare beast so far.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by the depedent upon social network.OAuth is the standardization and combined wisdom of many well established industry protocols. It is similar to other protocols currently in use (Google AuthSub, AOL OpenAuth, Yahoo BBAuth, Upcoming API, Flickr API, Amazon Web Services API, etc). Each protocol provides a proprietary method for exchanging user credentials for an access token

Each social service provider has implemented these OAuth specification  be it Google/Yahoo/MSN/facebook.
only difference can be in the way each service provider has implemented these specification.

In short you can also provide OAuth for your application all you  need to do is to implement these specification and set up your server to let the consumer of your application to use this.

Comment: what i meant was is OAuth implementaion same by all service providers? I guess its different based on your answer. Also what i really meant was is there any OAuth lib which will work for all services? I guess thats not possible as different services may have different implementations

Comment: they can be implementation wise different but when it comes to interact with the consumer they all have same set of request and response mechanism

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 1 is a specification, providers need to adhere to the specification or state reasons for deviating from the specification.

OAuth 2 is not yet a final specification, but a draft, still, I think most providers adhere to the draft fairly well.

In short, a good OAuth 1 library will work with any well implemented provider. I have less experience with OAuth 2 but I am fairly sure that the libraries there are less standardized.